# etw. werden / zu etw. werden

Tags: grammar

Ich möchte gerne wissen, was der Unterschied zwischen *zu etw. werden* und *etw. werden* ist.

Hier sind ein paar Beispiele:

> Wir müssen uns die Frage stellen, auf welcher Stufe ein Land **vollwertiges Mitglied werden** sollte.
>
> Der ECOFIN-Rat kann nicht **der "führende" Rat werden**.
>
> Die Mehrheitsentscheidung muss **das grundsätzliche Entscheidungssystem im Ministerrat werden**.
>
> Eine solche Bürgerschaftspolitik erfordert von den Organen der EU, dass auch sie **politischer werden**.
>
> Dieses bisher nationale Instrument muss jetzt **ein europäisches Instrument der Aufsicht und Kontrolle werden**.

---

> Mexiko ist **zum viertgrößten Erdölproduzenten der Welt geworden**. Aber in die Bundesrepublik fließt bisher kein Tropf.
>
> Mockus **wurde zum Symbol einer Bürgerbewegung**, die nach einer Alternative zu den klientelischen Parteiapparaten verlangte.
>
> Er muss in gleicher Weise wie das Europäische Parlament **zu einer zweiten legislativen Kammer werden**.
>
> Das hat die Folge, dass das Programm "Kultur 2000" **zu einem Programm der Bürger wird**.

Comment: Bei etwa der Hälfte der Beispielen kann man problemlos auch die jeweils andere Form schreiben.

Comment: @poke: Bei welchen denn nicht?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gute Frage. Mein erster Gedanke, bevor ich Deine Beispiele gelesen habe, war, dass *zu etwas werden* eine Verwandlung beschreibt:

> Ich werde Feuerwehrmann!

Aber:

> Wenn man mich reizt, werde ich zum Tier.

Bei all Deinen Beispielen bis auf „dass auch sie politischer werden“ scheint mir aber auch die jeweils andere Variante möglich zu sein. Diese eine Ausnahme liegt daran, dass “zu etwas werden“ nur mit Substantiven möglich ist.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht. "Eine solche Bürgerschaftspolitik erfordert von den Organen der EU, dass auch sie zu poitischen werden."

Answer (score 3):

"Etwas werden" beschreibt das Ergebnis der Handlung. "Zu etwas werden" beschreibt den Vorgang der Handlung.

Ich würde es ins Englische übertragen mit "to become" / "to turn to".

Comment: D.h., zum Studenten zu werden beschreibt den Akt, Student werden hingegen das Ergebnis? Durch die Immatrikulation werde ich Student - oder zum Studenten?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Man wird Student, wenn man das Ergebnis betrachtet, aber man wird zum Student, wenn man die Immatrikulation als (z.B. 2 Stunden zeitlich andauernden) Vorgang betrachtet.

Comment: Danke für diese Antworten!

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man **zu** etwas wird, ist damit eine Verwandlung verbunden. Man ist danach **nicht mehr das, was man vorher war.** Der vorherige Status geht verloren und wird durch einen neuen **ersetzt:**

> - Die Raupe wird zu einem Schmetterling. Sie ist danach keine Raupe mehr.
> - Mexiko wird vom fünftgrößten zum viertgrößten Erdölproduzenten der Welt. Mexiko ist danach nicht mehr der fünftgrößte Produzent.

Wenn man etwas wird (ohne *»zu«*) macht man eine Weiterentwicklung durch. Man **bleibt** das, was man vorher war, ist danach aber **zusätzlich** noch etwas anderes.

> - Laura will Lehrerin werden. Sie bleibt im Wesentliche wie sie ist, wird dann aber auch unterrichten dürfen.
> - Herr Schmidt wird Betriebsrat. Herr Schmidt macht weiterhin dasselbe wie vorher, übernimmt aber zusätzlich noch neue Aufgaben.

Comment: Danke für deine Antwort!

Answer (score 1):

*Zu* ist eine Richtungsangabe, für die ich besonders diese Motivationen sehe:

1. Eine Materialangabe: Wasser wird *zu Eis*, eine Lebewesen *zu Stein*. (trifft auf keines der genannten Beispiele zu)
2. Etwas allgemeiner gefasst: Ein **Zu**standsübergang: zu einer zweiten Kammer, zu einem Programm der Bürger
3. Etwas ist eine Skalenangabe, kann also auch messbar tiefer auf der Skala liegen; das trifft auf den viertgrößten Erdöllieferanten zu, sowie auf das *Symbol* (vorher ist man vielleicht einfach nur *engagiert* oder *Vorbild*)

Edit: Weil *werden* im Deutschen auch noch als Indikator für Futur (*wir werden verreisen*) und Passiv (*die Zutaten müssen gründlich vermischt werden*) dienen muss, halte ich alles, was diese Mehrdeutigkeit auflöst, für empfehlenswert, selbst wenn man im einen oder anderen Fall das *zu* weglassen könnte. (Bei *eine zweite Kammer werden* ist diese Mehrdeutigkeit maximal, das kann Futur, Passiv oder normales Verb sein.)

Comment: 1. "Das Wasser wird Eis" kann man nicht sagen? 2. "Eine zweite Kammer werden", "Es wird Programm der Bürger". 3. "X wird drittgrößter Erdöllieferant".

Comment: Einfaches _werden_ drückt allerdings auch schon eine Zustandsänderung aus, oder nicht?

Comment: Danke für diese Antworten!

Answer (score 1):

M.E. besteht der Unterschied darin, ob ein von anderen erteilter metaphorischer [Ruf](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image) <sup>oder [dwds.de 4.](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ruf)</sup> oder es eine wörtliche Position/Eigenschaft ist.

Bin ich **zu etwas geworden**, dann beurteilen genügend andere, dass ich die mit dem Etwas zugeschriebenen Ruf/Rolle/Image innehabe. Und dieses stellt eine Abstraktion/Metapher dar, weil ich konkret etwas anderes mache.

Bin ich **etwas geworden**, dann mache/bin ich genau das.

> Ich bin zur Feuerwehrfrau geworden.

vs.

> Ich bin Feuerwehrfrau geworden.

Im ersten Fall ist geht es um die Metapher, dass ich mehr als alle anderen mit meinem Tun/meinem Sein das verkörpere, was allgemein einer Feuerwehrfrau zugeschrieben wird. Es erfolgt also ein Vergleich innerhalb einer Gruppe von - hier Menschen - mit ihren Eigenschaften. Und wenn Not am Mann ist, bin ich als Feuerwehrfrau sehr schnell zur Stelle und mache, was im übertragenen Sinn [Feuerwehrfrauen in ihrem Berufsalltag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuerwehr) tun.

- Bspw. im Büroalltag bin ich sofort zur Stelle, nachdem der Beamer im Konferenzzimmer einfach nicht den Inhalt vom Laptop zeigen will und ich kann die Präsentation retten. Wörtlich habe ich keine Leben gerettet, angestellt bin ich als Schreibkraft - und trotzdem lässt sich abstrakt das Verhalten der Feuerwehr auf mein Verhalten übertragen. Kombiniert damit, dass in der Schrecksekunde nach mir gerufen wird und normalerweise alles funktioniert.

Im zweiten Fall habe ich die Ausbildung zur Feuerwehrfrau abgeschlossen bzw. eine Anstellung als Feuerwehrfrau angetreten. Ich werde also genau das tun, was eine Feuerwehrfrau [als Feuerwehrfrau](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feuerwehr) tut.

---

Dabei gibt es wie so oft eine Grauzone, die ich anhand der **Originalbeispiele** beleuchten will:

> Wir müssen uns die Frage stellen, auf welcher Stufe ein Land **vollwertiges Mitglied werden** sollte.  **<->** Wir müssen uns die Frage stellen, auf welcher Stufe ein Land **zu einem vollwertigen Mitglied werden** sollte.

- Das ist knifflig: Ist man Mitglied (werden) oder hat man den Ruf eines Mitglieds, ohne eins zu sein (zu werden)
- ein Mitglied kann offenbar nur "halbwertig" sein; das Erreichen der Stufe ist unabhängig davon, welche Art Mitglied man ist.
- ohne "zu" wird die entsprechende Mitgliedschaft bei Stufe X erteilt
- mit "zu" wird erwartet, dass mit dieser Stufe X ein mustergültiges Mitglieds-Verhalten einhergeht

> Der ECOFIN-Rat kann nicht **der "führende" Rat werden**. **<->** Der ECOFIN-Rat kann nicht **zu dem "führenden" Rat werden**.

- Kontextvermutung: es gibt mehrere Räte, keiner davon heißt "führender Rat"
- Der korrekte Satz wäre mit "zu" - denn es ist ein Image, dass der Ecofin-Rat eben nicht bekommen soll
- ohne "zu" impliziert der Satz, dass an einen der Räte formell die Zusatzbezeichnung "führend" vergeben wird

> Die Mehrheitsentscheidung muss **das grundsätzliche Entscheidungssystem im Ministerrat werden**.  **<->** Die Mehrheitsentscheidung muss **zum grundsätzlichen Entscheidungssystem im Ministerrat werden**.

- analog Ecofin: es gibt mehrere Entscheidungssysteme und keines hat diese Bezeichnung "grundsätzlich"; hat eines den Ruf, das "grundsätzliche" zu sein, dann sind die anderen faktisch bedeutungslos

> Eine solche Bürgerschaftspolitik erfordert von den Organen der EU, dass auch sie **politischer werden**. **<->** Eine solche Bürgerschaftspolitik erfordert von den Organen der EU, dass auch sie **zu Politischem werden**.

- Mit "zu" ist falsch
- die Organe der EU müssen politisch agieren - z.B. nicht nur behördlich agieren, sondern auch Politik machen

> Dieses bisher nationale Instrument muss jetzt **ein europäisches Instrument der Aufsicht und Kontrolle werden**. **<->** Dieses bisher nationale Instrument muss jetzt **zu einem europäischen Instrument der Aufsicht und Kontrolle werden**.

- ohne "zu" = Besagtes nationale Instrument soll als europäisches Instrument auf europäischer Ebene fortgeführt werden
- anstatt mit "zu": es soll ein nationales Instrument bleiben, dass mit der Macht eines europäischen Instruments eingesetzt wird

> Mexiko ist **zum viertgrößten Erdölproduzenten der Welt geworden**. Aber in die Bundesrepublik fließt bisher kein Tropf. **<->** Mexiko ist **der viertgrößte Erdölproduzent der Welt geworden**. Aber in die Bundesrepublik fließt bisher kein Tropf.

- Einerseits ist "zum" richtig, weil andere diese Einschätzung machen.
- Andererseits ist "zum" falsch, weil es keine Metapher, sondern eine faktische Feststellung ist und nur eine Rangordnung aller Erdölproduzenten vorgenommen wurde
- würde die Angabe "viertgrößter" fehlen, dann würde "zum" gleichbedeutend mit "zum größten" sein

> Mockus **wurde zum Symbol einer Bürgerbewegung**, die nach einer Alternative zu den klientelischen Parteiapparaten verlangte. **<->** Mockus **wurde ein Symbol einer Bürgerbewegung**, die nach einer Alternative zu den klientelischen Parteiapparaten verlangte.

- mit "zum" ist es das herausragende Symbol von allen, dass diese Bürgerbewegung charakterisiert
- ohne "zum" ist es nur eines von vielen Merkmalen, anhand derer diese Bürgerbewegung erkennbar ist

> Er muss in gleicher Weise wie das Europäische Parlament **zu einer zweiten legislativen Kammer werden**. **<->** Er muss in gleicher Weise wie das Europäische Parlament **eine zweite legislative Kammer werden**.

- Grenzfall, weil in der Gewaltenteilung die Legislative entsprechende operative statt nur metaphorische Aufgaben hat
- mit "zu" ist also eigentlich falsch, außer es wird indirekt Legislative betrieben, obwohl "Er" gar keine Befugnis/Aufgabe dazu hat
- ohne "zu" sagt aus, dass eine legislative Kammer eingerichtet werden soll und auf der Ebene, auf der "Er" dann analog dem EP arbeiten soll, gibt es bereits eine legislative Kammer

> Das hat die Folge, dass das Programm "Kultur 2000" **zu einem Programm der Bürger wird**.  **<->** Das hat die Folge, dass das Programm "Kultur 2000" **ein Programm der Bürger wird**.

- Grenzfall "zu einem" vs. "zu dem"
- mit "zu" ist es streng genommen kein von den Bürgern organisiertes/verantwortetes/... Programm, fühlt sich durch deren starke Beteiligung so an - anstatt nur ein behördliches Programm zu sein.
- ohne "zu" wird impliziert, dass die Bürger das Programm verantworten - und es ist eines von vielen

Comment: Danke für diese ausführliche Antwort!